# Silverstripe - Fresh installation no install page

Tags: silverstripe

I installed Silverstripe via Composer, just as described in the [Silverstripe lessons](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/up-and-running-setting-up-a-local-silverstripe-dev-environment-1).

It worked fine and the page is accessible by localhost.
I'm using XAMPP (newest version) with Apache and MySQL running.
Plugin php-intl is also enabled.

However, when I try to access the site it shows me the following message:

> SilverStripe Framework requires database configuration defined via .env

I should see an install page, but there's just this message.

It is a completely fresh Silverstripe project. No changes have been made.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Well, what about reading that message? Have you checked whether `.env` contains the proper settings? Additionally, why is this tagged with Composer or Xampp while the given message comes from a properly running application?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Silverstripe getting started guide](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/) we need to create a `.env` file and set it up with our environment variables.

W create a `.env` in our project root (not the `public/` folder). In this file we set up the minimum required environment variables. Replace the placeholders as required:

```
SS_DATABASE_CLASS="MySQLDatabase"
SS_DATABASE_NAME="<database>"
SS_DATABASE_SERVER="localhost"
SS_DATABASE_USERNAME="<user>"
SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD="<password>"

SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="admin"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="password"

SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"
```

Now we should be able to build our database by visiting `http://<local-website-url>/dev/build`.

Our website should be available on our local domain now.

Note, Silverstripe previously was packaged with an installer UI. This was removed from the core framework [in version 4.5](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/changelogs/4.5.0/#installer-ui) and moved into it's own separate [silverstripe-installer-wizard](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer-wizard) module. This can be added to the project by running `composer require silverstripe/installer-wizard`.

Comment: I used this: https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/up-and-running-setting-up-a-local-silverstripe-dev-environment-1 and there - for some reason the .env has to be configured while the install page is already showing up...

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. That lesson is now incorrect and would be misleading to any developers following it. The lesson needs to be updated to match the changes made to Silverstripe 4.5. The lesson was written before the installer wizard was removed from the core code.

Comment: I have raised this issue on the [Silverstripe lessons github repository](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-lessons-v4/issues/112). Thanks for pointing out this problem.